# floating divs are overlapping

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have the following code, its simplified to demonstrate the issue. The menuholder div is not inside the form div, but it is showing up that way. It needs to be to the right of it, any reason why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Website</title>

<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

#header {
width: 900px;
height: 600px;
border: 2px dashed #906;
}

#website {
width: 150px;
height: 90px;
float: left;
border: 2px dashed #F00;
}

#form {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
border: 2px dashed #906;

}
#menuholder {
width: 220px;
height: 200px;
float: left;
border: 2px dashed #30F;    
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<div id="website">
    <h1><a href="#">Website</a></h1>
</div>

<div id="form">          
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
        Username:
        </td>
        <td>
       <input type="text" name="username">
        </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>
        Password:
        </td> 
        <td>
        <input type='password' name='password'>
        </td>

    </tr>

<table>
<p>
<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Login'>
<p>
<a href='register.php'> Register!</a>
</div>

<div id="menuholder">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">register</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about application</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">demo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">help</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

On google inspect, it shows that the div menuholder is housed within the div of form. However, on my code, it is not. I was able to drag and drop in google inspect and it looks right. How do i fix my code to make it so i dont have to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The closing tag for your table should be `</table>`
- You're missing the closing `</form>` tag.
- The closing tag for your p tag should be `</p>`
- The inputs aren't closed properly (should end in `/>` not `>`

If you aren't already, I'd suggest tabbing in each time you open up an html node and tabbing out each time you close one. That will help you see where tags aren't closed.

Comment: and does the /form goes after the submit or before it?

Comment: After, it looks like it should come after your closing p tag

Answer (score 1):

A table? In a form?!

- Close your `<table>` tag
- Close your `<form>` tag
- Close your `<p>` tag

Comment: There's nothing a-semantic about a table in a form, it's a common way to line up labels and inputs.

Comment: Tables are for tabular *content*. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/tables.html or google it. The question of whether forms are tabular content or not is a matter of opinion, not standard. So, as it is not violating the standard it is therefore not a-semantic. In my experience it is the most reliable way to consistently line up a forms across all browsers.

Comment: A little harsh. Yes, you can have form elements in a table, should you need to present tabular data (editable database content, etc). A log in form is not tabular data (data is content is data..). You don't sum it, you don't count it. If Google (or anything else crawling your site for any reason) wanted to know what something is from it's HTML tag and you serve it up a log in form, you're not helping the internet. Semantic markup goes beyond broad interpretation of the spec.

Answer (score 1):

That opening comment could do with a close as well while we're at it..

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
```